# Syntax Error : Token 'a1' is unexpected, expecting [)] in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the code line as:

```
anchorTags[i].setAttribute("ng-click", "load("+count+")");
```

where `var count = "038932a1-0ca8-330b-3392-89b47bf77d42"`

The Error coming is :

```
Syntax Error: Token 'a1' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 21 of the
expression [load(038932a1-0ca8-330b-3392-89b47bf77d42)] starting at [a1-
0ca8-330b-3392-89b47bf77d42].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is a guid, not a number, so you need to pass it to `load()` as a string in quotes `''`:

```
anchorTags[i].setAttribute("ng-click", "load('"+count+"')");
```

Angular can parse the numeric part at the start of the guid `038932`, then gets confused by the non-numeric characters `a1-0c...`, hence that specific error message.